# Cross compile from Mac to Windows, from Linux to Windows, has differences?

Tags: go, cross-compiling

My coworker and I are both using Go 1.9 x64. I'm running Linux Mint 18.2 and he's running macOS Sierra 10.12.6. We ran the exact same script to cross compile a program for Windows x64 and out of curiosity we diffed the files to see how similar they would be. We expected to find a few build parameters or IDs to be different but it turns out there are a LOT of differences all throughout the files.

[image: meld <(hexdump -C one.exe) <(hexdump -C two.exe)]

We made sure the two programs were built off the exact same code. The program really doesn't do anything too OS specific. It reads a JSON file and executes a series of web requests determined by that file. Nothing like executing shell commands or reading/writing the windows registry. No CGO, the only use of the `os` package is `os.Exit(code)` calls, nothing stands out as a culprit.

Even though the programs were built from two different host OSes, they were both built for the same target OS with the same version of the Go compiler and the same code files. Why are the output binaries so different?

Comment: Is there a practical difference or is this just for trivia's sake?

Comment: We haven't run them yet. Need to get a hold of a windows machine or spin up a VM. I personally expect they'll both run just fine. It's more of an academic question until I notice a runtime difference.

Comment: Are you certain you're running the exact same release of Go. I would also expect only minor differences, since they are using the same compiler.

Comment: Output of `go version` on Linux: `go version go1.9 linux/amd64` and Mac: `go version go1.9 darwin/amd64`

Comment: Also a note about meld, the blue highlighted lines don't mean the entire line is different, just that a difference exists on that line. Browsing through some of the diff shows that most lines with differences only contain 1 or 2 different bytes. But there are sections like what's pictured where there are chunks of majorly differing code.

Comment: It might be worth comparing the output of `objdump` to see if there are any other differences. Are you certain that _every_ dependency is checkout out with the exact same code as well?

Comment: We use glide to be sure all the dependencies are on the same version. I'll get back to you about objdump.